# edit and update using jquery ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I've developed code to allow the user to edit and update details on the same page with AJAX methods. The update function is working perfectly.

Below I have some images. In the first image, I'm fetching user details from the database. I would like an "edit profile" button to replace the text above with corresponding input fields to allow edits. How can I achieve this? Through JQuery, AJAX or div?

**Before clicking edit button**

[image]

**After clicking edit button**

[image]

**PHP**

```
include('config.php');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ebusers WHERE UserID = '26'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<form id=updateform method=post action=update.php?id=" .$row['UserID']. ">";
    echo "<input type=text name=uname value=" .$row['UserName']. "><br>";
    echo "<input type=text name=uemail value=" .$row['UserEmail']. "><br>";
    echo "<button id=upd>Update</button><br>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "<hr>";
    echo "<span id=updateresult></span>";
}
```

**AJAX**

```
$("#upd").click( function() {
    $.post( $("#updateform").attr("action"),
        $("#updateform :input").serializeArray(),
        function(info){ $("#updateresult").html(info);
        });
    clearInput();
});

$("#updateform").submit( function() {
    return false;
});

function clearInput() {
    $("#updateform :input").each( function() {
        $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

**UPDATE.PHP**

```
include_once('config.php');
$getid = (int)$_GET['id'];
$name = $_POST['uname'];
$email = $_POST['uemail'];
if(mysql_query("UPDATE ebusers SET UserName = '$name', UserEmail = '$email' WHERE UserID = '$getid'"))
    echo "Successfully updated";
else
    echo "Failed to update records";
```

Comment: You could change the button text on click http://jsfiddle.net/2vpYs/

Comment: I am a bit confused about what you actually want to see. This should be pretty straight forward in AJAX and jQuery but what exactly do you want to see?

Comment: if user clicks the edit button the field should be change into textfield then only user can change their details. finally when they click update button it should be change normally. i've some images above.. see those images..

Answer (score 0):

You can fake this 'replace' with a 'switch' instead. Draw both a 'print version with edit button' and an 'update version with inputs and update button' and then swap between them, like this:

**PHP that creates the list**

```
include('config.php');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ebusers WHERE UserID = '26'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  ?>
  <div class="switch-group">
    <div class="update-form-wrap swappable">
      <form action="update.php?id=<?php echo $row['UserId'] ?>" metho="post" class="update-form">
        <input type="text" name="uname" value="<?php echo $row['UserName'] ?>" /><br/>
        <input type="email" name="uemail" value="<?php echo $row['UserEmail'] ?>" /><br/>
        <button class="update-btn swap" scope="switch-group" rel=".print-version">Update</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="print-version swappable">
      <span class="uname"><?php echo $row['UserName'] ?></span><br/>
      <span class="uemail"><?php echo $row['UserEmail'] ?></span><br/>
      <button class="edit-btn swap" scope="switch-group" rel=".update-form-wrap">Edit</button>
    </div>
    <span class="updateresult"></span>
  </div>  
  <hr/>
  <?php
}
```

**jQuery that does the swap**

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.swap', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var scope = $(this).closest($(this).attr('scope'));
  var rel = $($(this).attr('rel'), scope);
  scope.fine('> div').hide();
  rel.show();
});

$(".update-btn").click( function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var scope = self.closest(self.attr('scope'));
  $.post($("#updateform").attr("action"),
    $("#updateform :input").serializeArray(),
    function(info){ 
      $(".updateresult", scope).html(info.message);
      update_printout($(self.attr('rel'), scope), info.data);
    }
  );
});

$("#updateform").submit( function() {
  return false;
});

function update_printout(cont, data) {
  for (i in data) if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    $('span.'+i, scope).text(data[i]);
  }
}
```

**rough PHP to update and return json result**

```
include_once('config.php');
$result = array();

$getid = (int)$_GET['id'];
$result['uname'] = $name = $_POST['uname'];
$result['uemail'] = $email = $_POST['uemail'];
if(mysql_query("UPDATE ebusers SET UserName = '$name', UserEmail = '$email' WHERE UserID = '$getid'"))
  $result['message'] = "Successfully updated";
else
  $result['message'] = "Failed to update records";
echo @json_encode($result);
```

Something like that should do it. Make sure your update.php returns json. Use that json to udate the 'spans' that represent the data on the printout version. Swap on button clicks. That should sum you up.

Hope this helps.